# The BoxWord program is either facing a error, or it just does not run correctly

Tags: java

For AP Computer Science, I am creating a program where you take a word and make a box out of it:

Runner:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class BoxWordRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
         BoxWord bw = new BoxWord();
         //bw.setWord();
         bw.toString(4); 
         System.out.println( bw );
    }
}
```

Other program:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class BoxWord
{
    private String word;

    public BoxWord()
    {
        word="";
    }

    public BoxWord(String s)
    {
        word = s;
    }

    public void setWord(String w)
    {
        word = w;
    }

    public String toString(int num)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int z=0;
        String output = "";

        for(x=0;x<=num;x++)
            for(y=x;y<=num-x;y++)
              output += "*";
        for(z=num-x;z<=x;z--)
           output = output + "#";
        output += "\n";
        return output + "\n";
    }
}
```

There is a problem with the runner, especially with this line:

```
bw.setWord();
```

Commenting or deleting it causes the program to run, but not execute anything. 
That same problem can be done if you put an actual String within the ()'s, like "test". Leaving it on results in an error as shown:

```
BoxWordRunner.java:13: error: method setWord in class BoxWord cannot be applied to given types;
         bw.setWord();
           ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: I noticed when formatting your code that your `for` loop that uses the `z` variable is not executed for each iteration of your `x` or `y` loops. Judging by the whitespace and `z` loop, I think you want curly brackets {} from your `x` loop around your `y` and `z` loops to achieve what you intended.

Comment: Also you probably want `System.out.println( bw.toString(4));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a String argument to your `bw.setWord();` method call, such as `bw.setWord("hello")`;

Your toString method is confusing without brackets wrapping your for loop bodies.